# How to insert a one to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have a one-to-many relationship in between the `Home` model and `Phones` model

```
public function phones() {
    return $this -> hasMany(Phone::class);
}
```

and in Phone model:

```
public function homes() {
    return $this -> belongsTo(Home::class);
}
```

Now in my controller, when I insert the `Home`, I want to use it to be able to add unlimited numbers to the `Phone` table with the same `id` of `Home`. Here is how I insert now:

```
public function store(StoreHome $request) {
    $validated = $request -> all();
    if (!$validated) {
        return $this -> sendError('Validation Error.', $validated -> errors());
    }

    $home = Home::create($validated);
    return new HomeResource($home);
}
```

Now I want to know how can I insert `Home` with many `Phones` in phone table and realtionship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$post->comments()->createMany([
    [
        'message' => 'A new comment.',
    ],
    [
        'message' => 'Another new comment.',
    ],
]);
```

For details read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Update with example:

suppose you are using multiple input fields to take numbers input.

```
<input name="numbers[]">
<input name="numbers[]">

$phones = [];
$numbers = $request->input('numbers');
foreach($numbers as $number){
    $phones[] = [
        'number' => $number
    ];
}

$home->phones()->createMany($phones);
```

Comment: should i use foreach or can i pass an array to save many ??? because i want my user to send unlimted phone number

Comment: if you use foreach then using saveMany or createMany is useless. you shouldn't use foreach to create new records as it will run db queries for each items.

note: to prepare your array of phones you can use a foreach loop.

Comment: @Farshad i have updated my answer with more details (example)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created your Home, you can use `save` or `saveMany` on the relation :

```
$home->phones()->saveMany([
    new App\Phone(['phone' => '039049230490']),
    new App\Phone(['phone' => '039049223132']),
]);
```

You can find all doc here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: should i use foreach or can i pass an array to save many ??? because i want my user to send unlimted phone number

Comment: You can pass an array, I used an array in my example. You can save as many phones as you want.